# Async/Await promise being called twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, async.js

I'm trying to check if a connection exists after attempting to delete it. At this point the connection has already been deleted and it is now about to start checking once every second for 10 seconds. This is to make sure the user cant queue up multiple deletes before the first one has finished.

Everything seems to be working fine but I'm getting TWO `Connection not found. Deleted successfully`. I'm not quite sure why the `resolve()` portion of the code is being executed twice. Any help or advice would be great!

```js
  // delete_network_status set to running
  // connection deleted

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const checkDeleted = async (timeout_remaining) => {
      if (timeout_remaining <= 0) {
        ipc.server.broadcast("delete_network_status", "stopped");
        resolve();
      }
      try {
        // GetConnectionByUuid will fail if no connection exists
        await settings_iface.GetConnectionByUuid(toDeleteUUID);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Connection not found. Deleted successfully");
        ipc.server.broadcast("delete_network_status", "stopped");
        resolve();
      }
      console.log("Connection was found. Checking again...");
      await timeout(1000);
      await checkDeleted(timeout_remaining--);
    }
    
    //Set delay to 10 seconds
    await checkDeleted(10); 
  });
```

Comment: Calling `resolve()` doesn't exit from the function, so it will continue to the next `await checkDeleted(timeout_remaining--)` call when `resolve()` returns. You should return when you no longer need to repeat.

Comment: Although if that's the problem, this should be repeating infinitely, not just twice.

Comment: Hello Barmar, if you get any solution about this then please update it.